# Rails PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two models with simple belongs_to has_many relation, as follows:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio, optional: true
end

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Which were created by migrations:

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :status, null: false
      t.references :portfolio, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePortfolios < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :portfolios do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I want to create new Property with `portfolio_id: 1` which doesn't exist I'm getting an error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "properties" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_760fb8258a" DETAIL: Key (portfolio_id)=(1) is not present in table "portfolios".
```

How to handle such error and display to user information such as "portfolio_id doesn't exist" ?

Create action is pretty standard:

`property_controller.rb`

```
  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error makes sense, since you're trying to create a `property` with a `portfolio_id` that doesn't exist. Since you added the `optional: true` to `belongs_to :portfolio` in the Property class, you removed the validation that normally comes with the `belongs_to`.

The best way of avoiding that would be to display a dropwdown in the form for a new `portfolio` that contains all the possible properties. That would also be better in terms of UX because the user would not have to remember the id of a property.